# How to manage add zabbix templates to configured hosts without overwriting what is there?

Tags: ansible, zabbix

I am trying to use ansible to manage how templates are added to the configured hosts on my Zabbix server.  I am looking for a way to have the templates be added without overridding the templates that are already there.

For example, I have 5 servers.  I need them to be configured with the following templates:

- server0 needs Template A, B, C, D
- server1 needs Template A, B, C, E
- server2 needs Template A, B, C, D, F
- server3 needs Template A, B, C, G
- server4 needs Template D

I have the inventory file organized by the templates, since there are far less templates in my system than servers. In the Example it would look like:

```
[template_a_b_c]
server0
server1
server2
server3


[template_d]
server0
server2
server4
```

etc.
With the configuration like this, my ansible "zabbix" role has tasks for each template.  But for servers like server2, when the `template_d.yml` task runs, it will overwrite the templates that `tempalte_a_b_c.yml` linked.  This is the behavior I am trying to avoid.

I realize that I could reconfigure my ansible role to be organized by host and have a task for each, but I have hundreds of hosts and growing, so that will not scale.  Is ansible just not there yet or is there a flag in ansible's`zabbix_host` that I could make use of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct template list based on hosts' group membership and execute `zabbix_host` only once.

inventory:

```
[mygr1]
srv1
srv2
srv3

[mygr2]
srv2
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: mygr1:mygr2
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    template_map:
      mygr1: [template_a, template_b]
      mygr2: [template_c]
  tasks:
    - name: Generate template list
      set_fact:
        template_list: >
                       {{ group_names
                          | intersect(template_map.keys())
                          | map('extract',template_map)
                          | list
                          | sum(start=[]) }}
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ template_list }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [srv1] => {
    "msg": [
        "template_a",
        "template_b"
    ]
}
ok: [srv2] => {
    "msg": [
        "template_a",
        "template_b",
        "template_c"
    ]
}
ok: [srv3] => {
    "msg": [
        "template_a",
        "template_b"
    ]
}
```

`template_list` is formed in this sequence: take names of groups current host is member of, intersect it with known names from `template_map`, extract list of templates for each remaining name, convert result to list (from map-generator) and flatten resulting list of lists into single list.

Comment: I think this will solve the problem, however, I just figured out that my original problem is a limitation in Ansible's `zabbix_host`. In fact, it appears that in this module `force: no` is hard coded to fail in versions < 2.5.x. 
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/22614/files

But this is a good work around until v2.5.0 is released. (TBD)